# How to convert SELECT into SELECT JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I'm trying to convert my `SELECT` query into a faster version of `SELECT` including `JOIN`, that I found online.

Here is my code:

```
$stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM books WHERE person_id = :person_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5, 10");
```

**convert to**:

```
SELECT  l.id, value, LENGTH(stuffing) AS len
FROM    (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    t_limit
        ORDER BY
                id
        LIMIT 150000, 10
        ) o
JOIN    t_limit l
ON      l.id = o.id
ORDER BY
        l.id
```

---

I found that code [online](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/) (last piece of code). Its supposed to help with performance when doing `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`. anyways... here is what **i tried**:

```
$stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM books WHERE person_id = :person_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5, 10) o WHERE person_id = :person_id JOIN books l ON l.id = o.id ORDER BY l.id");
```

but it does not seem to work.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are the tables you're trying to join, and what values are you trying to join together.  Your second query is structured wrong and the * makes it confusing as to what columns you're trying to get from where

Comment: Why do you need a faster version? What is the issue with your existing code? How many rows matches `person_id`? Do you just need an index on that column instead? What does explain say for the query?

Comment: @MasonStedman I put the link of where i got the code in the op.

Comment: @MatsLindh I put the link of where i got the code in the op.

Comment: @baileyJchoi I need to know what you're trying to do I understand what the original code does.  From what I can see in there you're trying to join a table to itself (and your syntax is wrong for doing that) which isn't what joins are for.

Comment: @MasonStedman so I figured it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50183855/6585321. But the problem is that my old code is still faster. Maybe I don't have enough data? let me try it with more data

Comment: Your problem is that you're doing it wrong and you're original code was the proper way to do it in the first place. This is likely an indexing issue and not a query issue.  Can you post an explain on the query?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. If it's fast enough today, don't start fubaring it with "magic" code that you'll never need for your use case.

Comment: @baileyJchoi "Doesn't work" won't help us help you!!!  What does it mean???  No result???  Wrong result???  Error out???

Comment: If your query is too slow, I would suggest to rewrite this question (or create a new one) that just states your query and ask how you can optimize it. It also helps to include the timing, the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` and `EXPLAIN SELECT`

Answer (score 2):

> I found that code online. Its supposed to help with performance when doing OFFSET and LIMIT.

Where did you hear that? The statement you've quoted appears to be very specific to a particular database schema, and is not applicable to your situation. Forget about it.

As it stands, the SQL statement you are currently using is already optimal. If it is not performing adequately, you may need to create an index on `books (person_id, id)`.

Comment: I put the link of where I got the code from in the edited post

Comment: That link is VERY clearly about skipping 150000 rows, whereas you need only to skip 5, so why would you want this? LIMIT 150000,10 is quite something different than LIMIT 5, 10.

Comment: @Roemer originally i needed the structure like the joins, etc... I would change the numbers to my own use

Answer (score 1):

Here's two articles describing the seek method:

```
https://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/
```

and

```
https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page
```

It looks like a better fit for what you're doing.  I would still venture to guess this is an indexing issue, that an explain would help with.

Answer (score -1):

if anyone is wondering, I fixed it. I put the `WHERE` clause in the wrong place.

This is the fixed version now:

```
$stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM books WHERE person_id = :person_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5, 10) o JOIN books l ON l.id = o.id WHERE person_id = :person_id ORDER BY l.id");
```

Comment: Your problem is that you're doing it wrong and you're original code was the proper way to do it in the first place.  This is likely an indexing issue and not a query issue.

Comment: @MasonStedman hmm... pls check this link out: https://explainextended.com/2009/10/23/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-late-row-lookups/. im just learning about performance so i want to know what the that article is even about

Comment: The case in question specifically applies to using very large limit\offests with a specific schema.  You really shouldn't be using offset \ limit to implement pagination regardless as you'll see dips in performance regardless as your data set grows

Comment: Seek methods are a much better way to go for large data sets.

Comment: @MasonStedman thank you for that. can you please point me to what "seek methods" are?